# Swift - How to find the index of an item that is in an array within an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am only 10 years old an I am making a War (The Card Game) app. In the war app, I had to put arrays within arrays. How would I find an index of an item in this kind of array? **Here's an example where I would get an error:**

```
var card_array = [["2_of_clubs", "2_of_diamonds", "2_of_hearts", "2_of_spades"],
                  ["3_of_clubs", "3_of_diamonds", "3_of_hearts", "3_of_spades"],
                  ["4_of_clubs", "4_of_diamonds", "4_of_hearts", "4_of_spades"],
                  ["5_of_clubs", "5_of_diamonds", "5_of_hearts", "5_of_spades"],
                  ["6_of_clubs", "6_of_diamonds", "6_of_hearts", "6_of_spades"],
                  ["7_of_clubs", "7_of_diamonds", "7_of_hearts", "7_of_spades"],
                  ["8_of_clubs", "8_of_diamonds", "8_of_hearts", "8_of_spades"],
                  ["9_of_clubs", "9_of_diamonds", "9_of_hearts", "9_of_spades"],
                  ["10_of_clubs", "10_of_diamonds", "10_of_hearts", "10_of_spades"],
                  ["jack_of_clubs2", "jack_of_diamonds2", "jack_of_hearts2", "jack_of_spades2"],
                  ["queen_of_clubs2", "queen_of_diamonds2", "queen_of_hearts2", "queen_of_spades2"],
                  ["king_of_clubs2", "king_of_diamonds2", "king_of_hearts2", "king_of_spades2"],
                  ["ace_of_clubs", "ace_of_diamonds", "ace_of_hearts", "ace_of_spades"]]
var locationBottom = card_array.index(of: ["4_of_spades"])
var locationTop = card_array.index(of: ["king_of_diamonds2"])
print(locationTop)
print(locationBottom)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want is:

```
var locationBottom = card_array[0].index(of: "4_of_spades")
var locationTop = card_array[0].index(of: "king_of_diamonds2")
```

Instead, you're looking for an instance of an array containing solely one card in an array that contains an array of all 52 cards.

Comment: Thank you, I'm understanding this now

Answer (score 0):

The first answer might be correct, but it's not as good as the following since calling an index of an array without checking if it exists will crash your program. :)

Below is an example where you first flatten the nested arrays down to one array, and the use the `if let` syntax to check for an optional value which is the index.

Then it prints the indexes to the console. I've also included a print statement of the flattened array for you to see what it looks like.

```
var card_array = [["2_of_clubs", "2_of_diamonds", "2_of_hearts", "2_of_spades"],
              ["3_of_clubs", "3_of_diamonds", "3_of_hearts", "3_of_spades"],
              ["4_of_clubs", "4_of_diamonds", "4_of_hearts", "4_of_spades"],
              ["5_of_clubs", "5_of_diamonds", "5_of_hearts", "5_of_spades"],
              ["6_of_clubs", "6_of_diamonds", "6_of_hearts", "6_of_spades"],
              ["7_of_clubs", "7_of_diamonds", "7_of_hearts", "7_of_spades"],
              ["8_of_clubs", "8_of_diamonds", "8_of_hearts", "8_of_spades"],
              ["9_of_clubs", "9_of_diamonds", "9_of_hearts", "9_of_spades"],
              ["10_of_clubs", "10_of_diamonds", "10_of_hearts", "10_of_spades"],
              ["jack_of_clubs2", "jack_of_diamonds2", "jack_of_hearts2", "jack_of_spades2"],
              ["queen_of_clubs2", "queen_of_diamonds2", "queen_of_hearts2", "queen_of_spades2"],
              ["king_of_clubs2", "king_of_diamonds2", "king_of_hearts2", "king_of_spades2"],
              ["ace_of_clubs", "ace_of_diamonds", "ace_of_hearts", "ace_of_spades"]]

let flatCardArray = card_array.flatMap({$0})
print(flatCardArray)

if let locationBottom = flatCardArray.index(of: "4_of_spades"), let locationTop = flatCardArray.index(of: "king_of_diamonds2") {
    print("index of locationTop is: ", locationTop)
    print("index of locationBottom is: ", locationBottom)
} else {
    print("oh no, couldn't find indexes!")
}
```

Or you could do

```
for (number, array) in card_array.enumerated() {
    if let locationBottom = array.index(of: "4_of_spades") {
        print("index of locationBottom is: ", locationBottom, ", in array number: ", number)
    }
    if let locationTop = array.index(of: "king_of_diamonds2") {
        print("index of locationTop is: ", locationTop, ", in array number: ", number)
    }
}
```

Comment: Mea culpa.  I'm used to Objective-C; the equivalent method in Objective-C will return NSNotFound if an item is not found in an NSArray.

Comment: @TimKokesh That sounds kinda nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using square array, so you have to find two indexes: one for a row, another for a column, here is a simple example:

```
let elementToFind = "king_of_diamonds2"
var columnIndex:Int?
var rowIndex:Int? = card_array.index(where: { (arrayInside) -> Bool in
    columnIndex = arrayInside.index(where: { (string) -> Bool in
        return string == elementToFind
    })
    return columnIndex != nil
})

print("Row: \(rowIndex!) Column: \(columnIndex!)")
```